# how to for loop the bootstrap grid

Tags: python, html, django, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make it like the following: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/examples/pricing/
it shows the screen divided into three section
so it should be like this I think...

```
 <div class="row mb-2">
            <div class="col-4 bg-danger">
                .col-4
            </div>
            <div class="col-4 bg-warning">
                .col-4
            </div>
            <div class="col-4 bg-success">
                .col-4
            </div>
        </div>
```

But the problem is I am using django jinja template and for loop. so it groups the whole content.

This is my code but it won't do what's like in the link

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6 col-md-4">
        <div class="card">
        {% for all_episode in episode %}
        <a href="{% url 'episode_detail' slug=all_episode.slug %}"><img class="card-img-top" src='{{all_episode.image.url}}'></a>
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">
                  <a href="{% url 'episode_detail' slug=all_episode.slug %}">{{ all_episode.title }}</a>
                </h5>
                <p class="card-text">{{ all_episode.story |slice:":100" }}...</p>
            </div>

<div class="card-footer">
                <small class="text-muted">
                  <span class="h5">
                  <a href="{% url 'series_detail' slug=all_episode.series.slug %}">{{ all_episode.series }}</a>
                </span> / 
            <span class="h6"><a href="{% url 'season_detail' slug=all_episode.season.slug %}">{{ all_episode.season }}</a></span></small>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}




    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: you need to know episodes qty, then you could set  col-md-**X** where x = 12/episodes qty ... in the example qty = 3 then use col-md-**4**

Comment: @Mate I dont understand what u mean

Comment: How many sections do you need?